# 00905. 00000 - "missing keyword"

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to SQL and I'm stuck with creating the table

```
CREATE TABLE Recording(
    recordingID int not null,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    nameRec varchar(255) not null,
    price DOUBLE not null,
    quantityStock int not null,
    musicID int not null,
    StockDiscNum int not null,
    orderNums int not null,
    FOREIGN KEY(orderNums) REFERENCES Orders (orderNumber),
    PRIMARY KEY(recordingID) 
);
```

I checked every type but not sure why it say missing keyword
Thank you

What is the exact issue and the exact way to create table in SQL

Comment: How is your `OrderNumber` FK table defined?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE Orders(
  orderNumber int NOT NULL,
  orderDate date NOT NULL,
  quantity int not null,
  customerNums int not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (customerNums) REFERENCES Customer (customerNums),
  transactionId int Not null,
  paymentID int,
  PRIMARY KEY(orderNumber)
);`
@ViaTech

Answer (score 1):

There's no `DOUBLE` datatype in Oracle; use `NUMBER` instead. Also, Oracle recommends us to use `varchar2` instead of `varchar`.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Recording
  2  (
  3     recordingID     INT NOT NULL,
  4     title           VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
  5     nameRec         VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL,
  6     price           NUMBER NOT NULL,
  7     quantityStock   INT NOT NULL,
  8     musicID         INT NOT NULL,
  9     StockDiscNum    INT NOT NULL,
 10     orderNums       INT NOT NULL,
 11     FOREIGN KEY (orderNums) REFERENCES Orders (orderNumber),
 12     PRIMARY KEY (recordingID)
 13  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much that actually solved my problem and I changed all varchar to varchar2.  Thanks a lot!!